# Unable to create large spacing between lines in a paragraph with\setlength{\baselineskip}{10em}

Tags: line-spacing, baseline

Quoted from https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Paragraph_formatting#Line_spacing:

> **`\baselineskip`**
>
> Is a length determining the minimum space between the bottom of two successive lines in a paragraph; it may be changed (in the preamble) by `\setlength{\baselineskip}{value}`. Where *value* is set using any of the [LaTeX units](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Lengths_in_LaTeX).

This does not work for me. Here is my code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{10em}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam aliquet
eros nec purus elementum scelerisque. Curabitur ut libero erat. Fusce
felis purus, varius quis ex et, sollicitudin consequat risus. Donec id
turpis ut purus fermentum molestie. Praesent tincidunt porttitor lectus
eu aliquam. Nam vitae egestas magna. Phasellus justo diam, rutrum quis
arcu sit amet, volutpat ullamcorper tellus. Etiam nec sapien sit amet
erat posuere dapibus quis et ante.
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Why is there no large spacing between the bottom of successive lines in the paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is set at begin document so:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{10em}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam aliquet
eros nec purus elementum scelerisque. Curabitur ut libero erat. Fusce
felis purus, varius quis ex et, sollicitudin consequat risus. Donec id
turpis ut purus fermentum molestie. Praesent tincidunt porttitor lectus
eu aliquam. Nam vitae egestas magna. Phasellus justo diam, rutrum quis
arcu sit amet, volutpat ullamcorper tellus. Etiam nec sapien sit amet
erat posuere dapibus quis et ante.
\end{document}
```

Comment: note that it is better to use the latex font selection mechanism to specify a larger baseline otherwise any font command will reset it (as the `\normalfont` in `\begin{document}` did in your example)